# how we can edit drivers from windows iso file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, installation, iso-image

I want to delete some built-in drivers from win7 or win-vista iso file, is it possible?
where is the driver location in iso file please?
and how can we recognize the type of that, for example chipset,sound card,graphic or ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are looking to create a custom Windows install disc.  This can have your custom drivers included and remove any bloat drivers you don't want. [Here is one tutorial](http://lifehacker.com/5793427/how-to-create-a-custom-windows-installation-dvd-or-usb-install), summarized below:

1. Download and install [RT Se7en Lite](http://www.rt7lite.com/)
2. Import the Windows ISO to be customized
3. Remove undesired components and add desired drivers using the wizard
4. Export the modified install to an ISO or a USB key

Comment: Can you summarize the tutorial in your answer in case the link goes dead?

Comment: Absolutely, The basic summary is: Download http://www.rt7lite.com/, import the iso to be customized.  Following the wizard, remove components that are undesired and add the drivers that are.  From there you can export the final copy to an iso or a USB stick.  The software is pretty easy to follow.